# How can I override the default button style of Angular Datables buttons

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, angular-datatables

When I add buttons to my Angular Datatables, it creates them with default themeing, which is causing the buttons to look different from the rest of my page (see Column Visibility button in the image below):

[image]

I have tried playing with CSS to get the buttons to mimic the Bootstrap buttons (like the other buttons on the page), but I'm not having much luck.  I tried adding my CSS values to `button.dt-button, div.dt-button, a.dt-button {}` but had to override everything with `!important` which didn't seem right to me.

I also tried adding `bower_components/datatables/media/css/buttons.bootstrap.css` to my page `<links>` but it also had no effect.

Is there a pretty straight forward way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I use to remove the `dt-button` references. `dt-button` seems to cause all the trouble. It is dataTables own attempt to style different tags to a unified button look and this conflicts with bootstrap. So to have dataTables buttons that looks like the rest of the BS3 layout I add bootstrap classes to `className` :

```
.withButtons([ 
   { extend: 'pdf', 
     className: 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' 
   }  
])
```

and remove any `dt-button` reference in `initComplete` :

```
.withOption('initComplete', function() {
  $('.dt-button').removeClass('dt-button')
})
```

This ensures that the buttons is pure BS with no extra styling. I am sure this is *not* the "correct" way to do this. In theory there should be a working combination of `withBootstrap()` and `withButtons()` along with adequate package versions, but have never been able to find one successfully. I get *all* packages by CLI and do not want to mingle around with packages manually.

```
datatables.net
datatables.net-bs
datatables.net-buttons
angular-datatables
```

I believe the .net packages have low priority compared to dataTables download builder, cdn and github. They are not in sync.

Comment: See my answer above - this may be a more direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust accordingly but in my case I added:

```
display: inline;
```

to the css of the elements on the left that are floating above.  In my case (jQuery / Rails / Bootstrap) I was adding Buttons and the Bootstrap theme messes things up too (as mentioned above).

For bonus points you can override the default CSS classes on the elements:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.dom

So in my case (CoffeeScript notation):

```
$ ->

  locations = $('#locations').dataTable
    dom: 'Bfrtip'
    ajax: 
      url: $('#locations').data('source')
      type: 'GET'
    order: [[ 3, 'desc' ], [ 2, 'desc' ]]
    processing: true
    serverSide: false
    responsive: false
    buttons:
      dom:
        container:
          className: 'btn-group'
        button:
          className: 'btn btn-primary btn-outline'
```

This gets rid of the `dt-buttons` and `dt-button` which allows the base BS CSS to work properly.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-outline buttons-copy buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="locations" href="#">
    <span>Copy</span></a>
  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-outline buttons-pdf buttons-html5" tabindex="0" aria-controls="locations" href="#">
    <span>PDF</span></a>
</div>
```

This then output the proper BS buttons.